# How to select only rounded amounts in SQL Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, aggregation

I have column in table in SQL Teradata. Column looks like below:

```
col1
145.88
1678.99
140.00
130.00
```

And My question is how can I in Teradata SQL select only these rows where is rounded amounts so only 140.00 and 130.00 ?

Comment: Please include the table definition, in particular, include the _type_ of the column whose data you have shown above.

Comment: Assuming it's a numeric column`where col1 mod 1 = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about a special Teradata solution but in standard SQL one way to do this is to compare the value with a rounded version:

```
WHERE col1 = round(col1, 0)
```